# Has the function srid(geometry) been removed or has the name changed?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, srid

I am in the process of restoring a database that relied on PostGIS version 1.5 functions to a newer Postgresql engine that leverages PostGIS 2.2 functions.  In my restore process, I receive the following error:

pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  function srid(geometry) does not exist.

I know this error is caused by a constraint on one of my tables that utilizes the srid(geometry) function.  I want to alter the constraint to use the new function name -- if it exists.  Has this function been removed or has it been renamed since PostGIS version 1.5?

I am unable to use the legacy PostGIS functions because I am restoring to an AWS RDS instance.  RDS instances do not allow the creation of functions that use C language libraries from the underlying OS for security reasons.  That is why I am in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function has indeed been renamed.

In Postgis 2.0, use [ST_srid](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_SRID.html).

Alternatively, following https://github.com/mapbox/osm-bright/issues/45 you can use `legacy.sql` or `legacy_minimal.sql` to bring those old functions into Postgis 2.0 for compatibility. You might find them in `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\<version>\share\contrib\postgis-<version>\` for Windows installations.

Comment: I will try st_srid in place of srid and see what happens on restoration of the database.  Once I finish that process I will update this thread with my results.

Comment: I would use the legacy.sql script and have in the past when restoring to a database server that I completely control.  I am restoring to an AWS RDS instance, which does not accept function creation that use underlying C language libraries that are stored on the OS disk.  I receive an error like this: pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  permission denied for language c.

Comment: After changing the name to the correct and updated one I was able to continue the restore process.  Thanks!